# Samsung AdHub - The method init(Context, String, AdSize) in the type AdHubView is not applicable for the arguments (Context, String, AdSize) - WHAT?

Tags: android, andengine

I am currently following the Samsung Adhub SDK documentation incorporating their ads into my AndEngine game, but I am getting the weirdest issue in my onCreate(). I am setting up my adHub as follows:

```
 AdHubView adhubView;
 Context context;
 adhubView.init(context, "Your Iventory ID", AdSize.BANNER);
```

But for some reason, .init is complaining about the following:

```
 The method init(Context, String, AdSize) in the type AdHubView is not applicable for the arguments (Context, String, AdSize)
```

This makes no sense. For other instances, I passed in this when context was needed, but it complained about the same thing. The above example is me specifying context directly and it still complains. I am confused.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.